# What permissions required for GitHub updateTeamsRepository GraphQL mutation?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to update team repository access in GitHub using the GraphQL API, but can't figure out what permission is required.

This is the GraphQL mutation (IDs replaced with dummies)

```
mutation { 
  updateTeamsRepository(input: { repositoryId: "R_gkOHDFeAMA", teamIds: ["T_t08M4ADOAS34T7kw"], permission: MAINTAIN }) {
    repository {
      id
      nameWithOwner
    }
    teams {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateTeamsRepository": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "FORBIDDEN",
      "path": [
        "updateTeamsRepository"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "message": "glenthomas does not have the correct permissions to execute `UpdateTeamsRepository`"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am an organization owner and have the highest level of access possible. I can modify the teams and all repository settings. I have this same error using both the GitHub GraphQL explorer or another GraphQL client with PAT.

Comment: I want to report that I can reproduce this behavior: I am the owner of the organization but I cannot use this graphql mutation. I can manually go in and change the role of a team via the browser, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/overview). Give the app the following permissions:

- Repository Administration Read/Write
- Organization Members Read/Write

You'll need to [get a token](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation) for your App, and then you can make the needed calls.

Note that in the future, the Organization Members Write permission may not be required for the GraphQL mutation, as it's currently not needed when adding teams to a repo via the REST API. See:
[[Bug] updateTeamsRepository requires very broad permissions that the REST API doesn't](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53727).